# Watching over one ng-model and applying the changes to another ng-model in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

I have the following work-case -

In html, I'm populating table data from an API response using `ng-repeat`. There are two different columns in the table both having different `ng-model`s. One column would be having the data that is obtained from the response while the other column would be blank when the table loads.

What I'm looking for is **when the user enters some value in the second column and saves the data, the data should then be reflected in the first column**.

I used `$watch` in the loop but apparently the value that is obtained at the last iteration of the loop is stored and reflected in the first column. I also looked into watchGroup but that is valid for Angular versions 1.3 and above while the version that I'm using is 1.1

HTML -

```
<div ng-repeat="data in response">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="dt in data track by $index">
      <td>
         <input id="oldValue_{{$index}}" ng-model="dt.oldValue[$index]" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="newValue_{{$index}}" ng-model="newValue[$index]" />
      </td>
      <td>
        {{dt.otherData}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="save" ng-click="saveData()">Save</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="save" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Controller -

```
angular.module("MyApp",[])
.controller("MyCtrl",[]);
function MyCtrl() {
$scope.saveData = function() {
  for(var i=0; i<$scope.response.length; i++) {
    for(var j=0: j<$scope.response[i].innerData.length; j++) {
      var oldData = document.getElementById("oldValue_"+j).value;
      var newData = document.getElementById("newValue_"+j).value;
        if(newData > 0) {
          $scope.$watch('newValue['+j+']', function(newVal) {
          $scope.dt.oldValue[j] = newVal;
          },true);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's an image giving a brief idea of the issue -

[image]

EDIT -

The response json object is as such *(field sselected - measurementData is the one that is displayed in first column)* -

[image]

Also the response is as such -

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "OuterData": [
    {
      "InnerId": 4,
      "InnerData": [
        {
          "CollectionId": 35,
          "CollectionData": [
            {
              "DataId": 81,
              "CoreData": [
                {
                  "quantityUnitName": "Unit_1",
                  "quantityUnitSymbol": "UnitSymbol_1",
                  "dataUpdateDateTime": "2017-04-27T05:28:11Z",
                  "lastReadingDateTime": "2017-04-29T14:57:42Z",
                  "measurementData": 400.0
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "ExtraData": [
            {
              "quantityUnitName": "Unit_1",
              "quantityUnitSymbol": "UnitSymbol_1",
              "dataUpdateDateTime": "2017-04-27T05:28:11Z",
              "lastReadingDateTime": "2016-05-01T00:01:40Z",
              "measurementData": 521103.0
            },
            {
              "quantityUnitName": "Unit_1",
              "quantityUnitSymbol": "UnitSymbol_1",
              "dataUpdateDateTime": "2017-04-27T05:28:11Z",
              "lastReadingDateTime": "2016-05-01T00:01:40Z",
              "measurementData": 24814.428571428572
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "CollectionId": 24,
          "CollectionData": [
            {
              "DataId": 58,
              "CoreData": [
                {
                  "quantityUnitName": "Unit_2",
                  "quantityUnitSymbol": "UnitSymbol_1",
                  "dataUpdateDateTime": "2017-04-27T05:28:11Z",
                  "lastReadingDateTime": "2017-04-26T08:50:00Z",
                  "measurementData": 9925.0
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "DataId": 57,
              "CoreData": [
                {
                  "quantityUnitName": "Unit_2",
                  "quantityUnitSymbol": "UnitSymbol_1",
                  "dataUpdateDateTime": "2017-04-27T05:28:11Z",
                  "lastReadingDateTime": "2017-04-26T08:50:00Z",
                  "measurementData": 46285.0
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "DataId": 56,
              "CoreData": [
                {
                  "quantityUnitName": "Unit_2",
                  "quantityUnitSymbol": "UnitSymbol_1",
                  "dataUpdateDateTime": "2017-04-27T05:28:11Z",
                  "lastReadingDateTime": "2017-04-26T08:50:00Z",
                  "measurementData": 13465.0
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "ExtraData": [
            {
              "quantityUnitName": "Unit_2",
              "quantityUnitSymbol": "UnitSymbol_1",
              "dataUpdateDateTime": "2017-04-27T05:28:11Z",
              "lastReadingDateTime": "2016-05-01T00:01:40Z",
              "measurementData": 1561344.0
            },
            {
              "quantityUnitName": "Unit_2",
              "quantityUnitSymbol": "UnitSymbol_1",
              "dataUpdateDateTime": "2017-04-27T05:28:11Z",
              "lastReadingDateTime": "2016-05-01T00:01:40Z",
              "measurementData": 21685.333333333332
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "CollectionId": 30,
          "CollectionData": [
            {
              "DataId": 76,
              "CoreData": [
                {
                  "quantityUnitName": "Unit_3",
                  "quantityUnitSymbol": "UnitSymbol_1",
                  "dataUpdateDateTime": "2017-04-27T05:28:11Z",
                  "lastReadingDateTime": "2017-03-21T14:00:00Z",
                  "measurementData": 16370.0
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "ExtraData": [
            {
              "quantityUnitName": "Unit_3",
              "quantityUnitSymbol": "UnitSymbol_1",
              "dataUpdateDateTime": "2017-04-27T05:28:11Z",
              "lastReadingDateTime": "2016-05-01T00:01:40Z",
              "measurementData": 301720.0
            },
            {
              "quantityUnitName": "Unit_3",
              "quantityUnitSymbol": "UnitSymbol_1",
              "dataUpdateDateTime": "2017-04-27T05:28:11Z",
              "lastReadingDateTime": "2016-05-01T00:01:40Z",
              "measurementData": 15086.0
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "InnerId": 3,
      "InnerData": [
        {
          "CollectionId": 20,
          "CollectionData": [
            {
              "DataId": 40,
              "CoreData": [
                {
                  "quantityUnitName": "Unit_4",
                  "quantityUnitSymbol": "UnitSymbol_2",
                  "dataUpdateDateTime": "2017-04-27T05:28:11Z",
                  "lastReadingDateTime": "2017-04-01T10:39:00Z",
                  "measurementData": 0.0
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "ExtraData": [
            {
              "quantityUnitName": "Unit_4",
              "quantityUnitSymbol": "UnitSymbol_2",
              "dataUpdateDateTime": "2017-04-27T05:28:11Z",
              "lastReadingDateTime": "2016-05-01T00:01:40Z",
              "measurementData": 0.0
            },
            {
              "quantityUnitName": "Unit_4",
              "quantityUnitSymbol": "UnitSymbol_2",
              "dataUpdateDateTime": "2017-04-27T05:28:11Z",
              "lastReadingDateTime": "2016-05-01T00:01:40Z",
              "measurementData": 0.0
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "CollectionId": 18,
          "CollectionData": [
            {
              "DataId": 35,
              "CoreData": [
                {
                  "quantityUnitName": "Unit_5",
                  "quantityUnitSymbol": "UnitSymbol_3",
                  "dataUpdateDateTime": "2017-04-27T05:28:11Z",
                  "lastReadingDateTime": "2017-04-18T11:05:22Z",
                  "measurementData": 0.001135
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "ExtraData": [
            {
              "quantityUnitName": "Unit_5",
              "quantityUnitSymbol": "UnitSymbol_3",
              "dataUpdateDateTime": "2017-04-27T05:28:11Z",
              "lastReadingDateTime": "2016-05-01T00:01:40Z",
              "measurementData": 0.001135
            },
            {
              "quantityUnitName": "Unit_5",
              "quantityUnitSymbol": "UnitSymbol_3",
              "dataUpdateDateTime": "2017-04-27T05:28:11Z",
              "lastReadingDateTime": "2016-05-01T00:01:40Z",
              "measurementData": 0.001135
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "CollectionId": 40,
          "CollectionData": [
            {
              "DataId": 36,
              "CoreData": [
                {
                  "quantityUnitName": "Unit_5",
                  "quantityUnitSymbol": "UnitSymbol_3",
                  "dataUpdateDateTime": "2017-04-27T05:28:11Z",
                  "lastReadingDateTime": "2017-04-18T11:05:22Z",
                  "measurementData": 1.132728
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "ExtraData": [
            {
              "quantityUnitName": "Unit_5",
              "quantityUnitSymbol": "UnitSymbol_3",
              "dataUpdateDateTime": "2017-04-27T05:28:11Z",
              "lastReadingDateTime": "2016-05-01T00:01:40Z",
              "measurementData": 1.132728
            },
            {
              "quantityUnitName": "Unit_5",
              "quantityUnitSymbol": "UnitSymbol_3",
              "dataUpdateDateTime": "2017-04-27T05:28:11Z",
              "lastReadingDateTime": "2016-05-01T00:01:40Z",
              "measurementData": 1.132728
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "CollectionId": 10,
          "CollectionData": [
            {
              "DataId": 2,
              "CoreData": [
                {
                  "quantityUnitName": "Unit_6",
                  "quantityUnitSymbol": "UnitSymbol_4",
                  "dataUpdateDateTime": "2017-04-27T05:28:11Z",
                  "lastReadingDateTime": "2017-04-14T01:29:00Z",
                  "measurementData": 120.0
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "ExtraData": [
            {
              "quantityUnitName": "Unit_6",
              "quantityUnitSymbol": "UnitSymbol_4",
              "dataUpdateDateTime": "2017-04-27T05:28:11Z",
              "lastReadingDateTime": "2016-05-01T00:01:40Z",
              "measurementData": 15508.363130715883
            },
            {
              "quantityUnitName": "Unit_6",
              "quantityUnitSymbol": "UnitSymbol_4",
              "dataUpdateDateTime": "2017-04-27T05:28:11Z",
              "lastReadingDateTime": "2016-05-01T00:01:40Z",
              "measurementData": 1.2595113401052451
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does the user enters value for every row of ng-Model2 column? and is  that is to be reflected correspondingly

Comment: Can u give the $scope.response object

Comment: @JinsPeter its not required to enter for each row, it all depends on the user. Also the table that I've shown in the image is a small part, my actual case has 40-some rows.
Say the user enters 10 values at different rows, eg. row - 1 to 5, 10, 15 to 18, then these data should be reflected to the first column of the corresponding rows.
for the $scope.response object, its an API call response and the object is too large to share here. Still let me try to share a compact version of the response.

Comment: I just want to know where is your new newValue array in you controller. does $scope.newValue give the newValue array

Comment: Did u check every iteration the $watch get called or not?? I mean Did u check the newValue['+j+']' values passing on each iteration or not?

Comment: The newValue array that I'm passing in $watch is the ng-model for the second column in table. It isn't a part of the $scope.response object.

Comment: @S.M.Priya yes, for debugging purpose I added logs inside watch function, but the value obtained at the last iteration of the loop is only saved, and when the loop finishes the reflection of new data is done for only the value obtained at the last iteration, i.e the value saved by watch function

Comment: I understand the new Array is not in $scope.respone. but it should be either  a controller Obj or a scope obj may be $scope.newArray.

Comment: Also does ur response object look like this $scope.response ={
   obj1:{
      oldData = [1,2,3,4,5,7,5,78,41,5,4],
      otherData = [11,22,3,4,25,7,65,38,4,65,54]
    },
    obj2:{
     oldData = [1,2,3,4,5,7,5,78,41,5,4],
      otherData = [11,22,3,4,25,7,65,38,4,65,54]
    }
   
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this? Its just simple example changes will be require according to you response data.

```js
var MyApp = angular.module("MyApp",[]);
MyApp.controller("MyCtrl",['$scope',MyCtrl]);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.data= [1,2,3,4,5];
$scope.newValue = [];
$scope.saveData = function() {
   if($scope.newValue.length > 0) { 
    angular.forEach($scope.newValue,function(v,k){        
        $scope.data[k] = v;   
    });
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp"  ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="dt in data track by $index">
      <td>{{dt}}
         <input id="oldValue_{{$index}}" ng-model="dt" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input id="newValue_{{$index}}" ng-model="newValue[$index]" />
      </td>
      <td>
        {{dt.otherData}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="save" ng-click="saveData()">Save</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="save" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well the usage in my case is quite similar to what you displayed. However, I was looking for using $watch in my case. But using your approach, i.e angular.forEach, I made some changes in my code and it worked for me. So I'll accept your answer as my problem got solved using your method.

Comment: I will suggest this way. Use $watch when you want to update object without any event.. but here you have click event so use angular.forEach. and also $watch decreases performance when it is more complicated.

Comment: oh, thanks! Also the list is quite long, about 40-50 entries; in this case would using $watch hinder the performance in some way?

Comment: @Trivedi yes it is.